# SecurityAgent causing a freeze

Tags: macos, performance, login

Intermittently, I witness a freeze with my MacPro and I was wondering if anyone has had a similar freeze and found a cure. Some background: I have my screen saver turned off. I have Energy Star set to never put the computer or the display to sleep. I generally Switch out to the Login Dialog and turn my monitor off because often times I remote into this computer and it freaks family members out when they see a computer operating by themselves...

On to the issue. Occasionally, when I turn my monitor back on, I see a dark screen with the remnants of the Flurry screen saver drawn to the screen. Note, it's frozen and nothing is responding. Often times, I can use the Eject button on my keyboard to "shock" the system into responding and it brings up the Login Dialog and I can continue as normal. However, sometimes, even this trick doesn't work. Then, what I have to do is use my laptop to ssh into my MacPro and `sudo kill -9` the process for

```
root     12856   0.0  0.0  2476680   2420   ??  S     5:18PM   0:00.08 /System/Library/CoreServices/SecurityAgent.app/Contents/Resources/authorizationhost
```

Which then clears the dead Flurry screen saver image and brings up the Login Dialog and again, everything works as normal.

So, does anyone else have this situation? Do they have a better way to fix it so that this problem doesn't happen?

Note: I am using Mac OS X 10.6.8. Alternatively, if someone had this problem and upgraded to 10.7, was the problem fixed?

Comment: The problem has (returned|continued) so I am un-answering this question in the hopes that someone else can help me solve this!

Comment: As an FYI for anyone else that runs across this question: OS X also appears to spawn new SecurityAgent processes for each VNC session connecting to the machine with no apparent maximum threshold.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that the cable from the monitor to the power box wasn't fully connected. I noticed this a few days ago and made sure the cable was fully connected and I haven't had my issue since. At this point, it's just anecdotal evidence, but I wanted to log the answer in case others were having the same issue. Make sure your cables are fully connected!

**UPDATE** I received a new monitor for the holidays but it forced me to purchase a new monitor card, one that could handle `Mini DisplayPort`. Now that I have swapped out the monitor card, this problem is not happening anymore. So it seems it was related to the hardware, but more likely the card had some issue that was causing the problem.